# How to have bot send message to 'general' channel, or channel that has most messages?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot where it sends a message at a certain time every day to the guild. I am using `cron` for the scheduled message, but not sure what code to write for the bot to send the message to the 'general' channel of a guild, and if they don't have a 'general' channel, send to the channel with the most activity or messages.

Since `defaultChannel` was removed, not sure how I should go about this. Also, I don't want to send the message to a specific channel using channel id because I want to make this bot public so a lot of different guilds can use.

```
 cron.schedule('00 45 12,20 * * *', () => {

      //code to send a message to guild's 'default channel' or 'channel with most activity goes here'
}, {
    scheduled: true,
    timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"}
);
```

It doesn't necessarily have to send to 'default' channel or channel with most messages. These are just the options I came up with. Basically, I want the message to go out to just 1 channel where everyone can see it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This guide should be able to help you.](https://anidiots.guide/frequently-asked-questions#default-channel) Although be careful with the first channel the bot can send in, this could be announcements as well.

My recommendation is using a configuration in a database though. This should allow people to set a channel where the message is being sent.

Answer (score -1):

1 way you could do this is to use the discord API to post messages. [POST message to channel via discord API](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message)

The issue with this is you'll have to know what the channel's ID is.